# Solving for the flow of a vector field in Sympy

Tags: python, sympy

I'm having trouble writing a function that solves for the [flow of a vector field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_(mathematics)#Autonomous_systems_of_ordinary_differential_equations) in Sympy. I'm very new to Sympy, although (back in my days) I have spent quite some time using Mathematica for symbolic computations.

My attempt :

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> def Flow(v):
        eps = Symbol(r'\varepsilon',real=True)
        Fl = Function('Fl')
        diff_eq = Eq(Derivative(Fl(eps),eps) , v(Fl(eps)))

        return dsolve(diff_eq,
            ics={Fl(0):x},
    )
```

This definition seems to work since for a very simple example I get the right answer:

```
>>> def v(x): return x
>>> Flow(v)

Eq(Fl(\varepsilon), x*exp(\varepsilon))
```

However, on a slightly more challenging example, I get the following error message:

```
>>> a = Symbol('a')
>>> def v(x): return x**a
>>> Flow(v)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/mnt/c/Boulot/Volumes/Covariant_ref_elem.ipynb Cell 4' in <cell line: 3>()
      1 a = Symbol('a')
      2 def v(x): return x**a
----> 3 Flow(v)

/mnt/c/Boulot/Volumes/Covariant_ref_elem.ipynb Cell 3' in Flow(v)
      3 Fl = Function('Fl')
      4 diff_eq = Eq(Derivative(Fl(eps),eps) , v(Fl(eps)))
----> 6 return dsolve(diff_eq,
      7     ics={Fl(0):x},
      8 )

File ~/anaconda3/envs/sympy/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sympy/solvers/ode/ode.py:640, in dsolve(eq, func, hint, simplify, ics, xi, eta, x0, n, **kwargs)
    637 else:
    638     # The key 'hint' stores the hint needed to be solved for.
    639     hint = hints['hint']
--> 640     return _helper_simplify(eq, hint, hints, simplify, ics=ics)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/sympy/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sympy/solvers/ode/ode.py:701, in _helper_simplify(eq, hint, match, simplify, ics, **kwargs)
    699 for s in rv:
    700     try:
--> 701         solved_constants = solve_ics([s], [r['func']], cons(s), ics)
    702     except ValueError:
    703         continue

File ~/anaconda3/envs/sympy/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sympy/solvers/ode/ode.py:793, in solve_ics(sols, funcs, constants, ics)
    791 # TODO: Use solveset here
    792 try:
--> 793     solved_constants = solve(subs_sols, constants, dict=True)
    794 except NotImplementedError:
    795     solved_constants = []

File ~/anaconda3/envs/sympy/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sympy/solvers/solvers.py:916, in solve(f, *symbols, **flags)
    911                 raise NotImplementedError(filldedent('''
    912                     Unanticipated argument of Eq when other arg
    913                     is True or False.
    914                 '''))
    915         else:
--> 916             fi = fi.rewrite(Add, evaluate=False)
    917     f[i] = fi
    919 if fi.is_Relational:

File ~/anaconda3/envs/sympy/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sympy/core/basic.py:1890, in Basic.rewrite(self, deep, *args, **hints)
   1887         return self
   1888 # hereafter, empty pattern is interpreted as all pattern.
-> 1890 return self._rewrite(pattern, rule, method, **hints)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/sympy/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sympy/core/basic.py:1895, in Basic._rewrite(self, pattern, rule, method, **hints)
   1893 deep = hints.pop('deep', True)
   1894 if deep:
-> 1895     args = [a._rewrite(pattern, rule, method, **hints)
   1896             for a in self.args]
   1897 else:
   1898     args = self.args

File ~/anaconda3/envs/sympy/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sympy/core/basic.py:1895, in <listcomp>(.0)
   1893 deep = hints.pop('deep', True)
   1894 if deep:
-> 1895     args = [a._rewrite(pattern, rule, method, **hints)
   1896             for a in self.args]
   1897 else:
   1898     args = self.args

File ~/anaconda3/envs/sympy/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sympy/core/basic.py:1895, in Basic._rewrite(self, pattern, rule, method, **hints)
   1893 deep = hints.pop('deep', True)
   1894 if deep:
-> 1895     args = [a._rewrite(pattern, rule, method, **hints)
   1896             for a in self.args]
   1897 else:
   1898     args = self.args

File ~/anaconda3/envs/sympy/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sympy/core/basic.py:1895, in <listcomp>(.0)
   1893 deep = hints.pop('deep', True)
   1894 if deep:
-> 1895     args = [a._rewrite(pattern, rule, method, **hints)
   1896             for a in self.args]
   1897 else:
   1898     args = self.args

File ~/anaconda3/envs/sympy/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sympy/core/basic.py:1909, in Basic._rewrite(self, pattern, rule, method, **hints)
   1907 if not args:
   1908     return self
-> 1909 return self.func(*args)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/sympy/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sympy/functions/elementary/piecewise.py:35, in ExprCondPair.__new__(cls, expr, cond)
     32         cond = cond.rewrite(ITE)
     34 if not isinstance(cond, Boolean):
---> 35     raise TypeError(filldedent('''
     36         Second argument must be a Boolean,
     37         not `%s`''' % func_name(cond)))
     38 return Tuple.__new__(cls, expr, cond)

TypeError: 
Second argument must be a Boolean, not `Add`
```

If you were to tell me that the ODE is too hard for sympy, I would be a bit surprised because I solved it by hand in the matter of a few minutes, but I would understand. I however fail to undestand why an error is raised.

Questions: Is my syntax wrong? Is the ODE too complex to be solved by Sympy? Why is an error raised and what does the error mean exactly?

Thank you for your help,

Comment: I'd start by stripping off all the function call fluff, and looking at the arguments in `dsolve(diff_eq, ics={Fl(0):x}`.  The traceback tells me it's trying to 'rewrite' this in some standard form.  It's not immediately obvious what's the `Add` instead of a `boolean`, but detail examination may clear that up.  And (re)read the `dsolve` docs.

Comment: This is a bug. Simplified reproducer: `dsolve(f(x).diff(x) - f(x)**y, ics={f(0):0})`. Please report this to GitHub.

Comment: Thank you @OscarBenjamin . If you write this up as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/23285